Github GraphQL API branch search with regex
I'm trying to get branch protection rules for certain branches only, following a regex pattern.
As it doesn't seem possible through REST API I'm switching to GraphQL API, but as a newbie I'm struggling to forge a correct query.
Is it even possible ?
edit : Here's an example of what I'm trying to get
query Repository {
    repository(name: "test", owner: "biologeek") {
        refs(refPrefix: "refs/heads/", first: 99, query: { regex: "feature/*" }) {
            nodes {
                branchProtectionRule {
                    id
                    pushAllowances(last: 99) {
                        nodes {
                            actor {
                                ... on User { 
                                    email
                                    login
                                    name
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                name
                prefix
            }
        }
    }
}


Please add your attempts so far.

Done. However the given example does not work
